# VB.NET Invalid cross-thread access

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a background worker control on a form.

In this form I have another form that shows a progress:

```
Private _fWait As frmWait
```

I am updating this form, change its label to tell the user what is currently going on.

When the background worker is finished, I want to close this form _fWait.

I am using

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    'do the background worker stuff. I have not stated it here because it is not important

    _fWait.Close()

    _bDone = True

End Sub
```

But I am getting the error "Invalid cross-thread access: The access to the control frmWait occured from a diffent thread than the thread it was created by." on the line "_fWait.Close()".

Can somebody tell me what I did wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: The backgroundworker does work on another thread, so any calls here are already on the diff thread. This is where you run long process work and then access controls in the worker_completed, or progress_changed events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `_fWait.Close()` is has to be called on the UI thread whereas the `BackgroundWorker1_DoWork` handler will be running on a different thread which is why you are getting the error. There are two options for closing the form:

1) Continue to close the form on the `DoWork` handler but marshal the request onto the UI thread using something like the code below:

```
this.Invoke(() => _fWait.Close());
```

It's been a while since I've done VB, so you'll have to convert the C# code into VB...sorry.

2) Handle the `RunWorkerCompleted` event and close it there. If you BackgroundWorker was started on 
the UI thread, then the `RunWorkerCompleted` will also be called on the UI thread.

If I remember right the `ProgressedChanged` event will also be called on the UI assuming that the `BackgroundWorker` was created on the UI thread. If the `BackgroundWorker` is created another another thread, then the `RunWorkerCompleted` and `ProgressChanged` will also be called on a separate thread and you will have to marshal calls to the UI as described above in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

In simple programs, you can ignore cross-thread errors by adding this to your Form.Load method:

```
CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
```

Note that it can cause problems when running multiple asynchronous threads that access shared data, so don't use it indiscriminately.

---

If multiple threads cause a shared routine to run, use [SyncLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t(v=vs.100).aspx) to prevent multiple simultaneous instances.

Comment: I do remember reading somewhere that the property you specified is more for debugging and an exception will still be thrown at runtime. Maybe someone else can confirm this. Either way simply ignoring these exceptions is not good practice and I would recommend ensuring that any UI work is done on the correct thread.